# JsonPath: How to get the whole tree except one node

Tags: java, jsonpath

everyone.

My question is quite simple, I think.

**My use case:**

Jenkins receives a huge JSON payload from a Gitlab WebHook (more than 2500 lines). I want to get rid of a specific node with more than 2000 lines. The JSON I get is so big that Jenkins is unable to parse it correctly so I want to remove a node I don't need.

Assume the sample tree in the [documentation page](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath):

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

How can I get the whole tree except one? For example, if I want to get everything but the *book* node ...

```
{
    "store": {
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I more or less understand the filters feature, and I assume I need to figure out a proper filter but it seems they are only useful to search nodes based on some criteria. I'm not sure if they are useful to remove elements based on filtering conditions.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Path is a tool for querying, not manipulation.  You're not going to be able to alter the input value with it.  You need another tool.

I'd suggest looking at something like https://jsonnet.org/ which is designed for template-based transformations and generation.