# Extract subset of json from given JsonPath

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jsonpath

I have a nested json structure and a list of json paths. I want to extract and return only those parts of json that are defined in the json paths.

For eg: Let's say the json contains:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": {
        "name": "ABCD",
        "email": "abcd@email.com",
        "phone": "1234"
    }
}
```

And I've the following JsonPath's

```
$.id
$.user.name
$.user.phone
```

So the json returned will be

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": {
        "name": "ABCD",
        "phone": "1234"
    }
}
```

I've tried multiple ways with Jayway's JsonPath but I only get the value, not the entire heirarchy(Eg: If I search for `$.user.name` then I get `ABCD` instead of `{"user": {"name": "ABCD"}}`).

I looked at [Extracting a subset of attributes with JSONPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447781/extracting-a-subset-of-attributes-with-jsonpath) but it does not answer the question of return entire json structure.

Any ideas how do I approach this? I suspect that I would need to build Jackson JsonNode iteratively using the JsonPath, but couldn't build a solution.

Note: The example above contains a simple json structure. In reality, I suspect to have many nested structures(even arrays) inside json.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68436665/878701. please see my answer there.

Comment: @gregsdennis I do not like introducing a completely new dependency for this very specific problem. I'm looking for some easy way to do it with jackson, gson and/or jsonpath.

Comment: JSON Path isn't the tool you need.  It's for querying. It doesn't do transformation.  That was the point of marking this as a duplicate.  I don't know about those other ones you mention.